# Any way to get Quartz's DailyTimeIntervalTrigger to run in alternate time zones?

Tags: java, timezone, quartz-scheduler

Using Java Quartz 2.2.1, I'm unable to find support for alternate (e.g. other than system default) time zones for DailyTimeIntervalTrigger. Does it exist, or does anyone know of a workaround?

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
DailyTimeIntervalTrigger t = newTrigger()
    .withSchedule(
        dailyTimeIntervalSchedule()
            .startingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(8, 0))
            .withIntervalInMinutes(15)
            .endingDailyAfterCount(3)
            .inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"))
            // inTimeZone not present on DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder
    )
    .build();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a [`CronTrigger`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06) for that?

Comment: Just one: these schedules are ultimately defined by non-technical users. Obtaining a few easily understood details like start/end times, interval, etc. and transferring them into a DailyTimeIntervalTrigger is much simpler (and consequently less error-prone) than translating these fields to cron-style expressions, or asking the user for the cron expressions directly. (That simplicity is, presumably, why DailyTimeIntervalTrigger exists in the first place; unfortunately it looks as if the Quartz developers left out one feature rather critical to this application.)

Comment: I see that the .Net port (Quartz.net) has this.  It looks like someone added it in [the pull request here](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/pull/81).  Perhaps you could review their implementation and backport it into Java.  I'm not familiar enough to help further - sorry.

Comment: I saw that too! Got my hopes up before realizing it was the .NET version. I may explore contributing the feature myself if it indeed does not exist. Thanks for your help!

Comment: nice query. You should be able to manage with Quartz with few of your own code tweeks

Answer (score 0):

check DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.html

it should be helpful

> add to this your own custom logic for TimeZone Handling, which should be able to increment or decrement the time of execution based on server time zone and time zone to which you intend to execute.

For example my server runs in GMT, my business ends at 6:00 PM PST.

To manage this I simply add/subtract a fixed number to compensate the time zone difference.

Comment: This would be a decent approximation but unless I'm mistaken, it would be incorrect at times, owing to differences in DST observance and timing. For example, on 2013-10-31, America/New_York (on DST) was UTC-4 and Europe/London (done with DST for 2013) was UTC+0. One week later, on 2013-11-07, America/New_York was UTC-5 and Europe/London was still UTC+0. Since this trigger is scheduled once and expected to run indefinitely, the offset needs to be correct for all future dates.

Comment: and I suppose because you know this limitation you will be able to handle that as well.

Comment: Accounting for these differences would take well beyond the time I wish to allocate to this -- not to mention that DST observance changes unpredictably and a given trigger is meant run indefinitely and would have to know about such differences in advance. Alas, not sure I have a choice beyond contributing the feature myself.

Comment: I am unsure of how DST is taken care of in java APIs. I would have suggested something in that case. Look at the bigger picture, you can take a decision to keep it same during DST. This is scheduled job to handle some business. I understand this to be a major reason why our server settings is set in GMT and not to show PST or EST timings

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround - it's not pretty. I have a similar situation: the User picks a day/days to run our service and we poll every x minutes. So that means I need to schedule the poller to run within the User's day (based on their timezone). So I create 1 or 2 (most likely 2) triggers that will cover the user's day.

Example: The User wants to run the service on Thursdays and they are in America/Chicago timezone
I will create 2 DailyTimeInterval Triggers to cover the day

Formally
America/Chicago Start: 4/28/16 12:00:00 AM CDT, End: 4/28/16 11:59:59 PM CDT 
which is equivalent to
UTC Start: 4/28/16 5:00:00 AM UTC, End: 4/29/16 4:59:59 AM UTC

The 1st trigger will run from
UTC Thursday 5:00:00  to 23:59:59
The 2nd trigger will run from
UTC Friday 0:00:00 to 4:59:59

Here is what my Java 7 code looks like

```
//SDF_DAY_TO_CALENDAR_DAY is a hashmap that translates from simpledateformat day of week to calendar
//simple date format day number of the week is 1=Monday 7=Sunday
//calendar day number is 1=Sunday 7=Saturday
private static final Map<Integer, Integer> SDF_DAY_TO_CALENDAR_DAY = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
    put(1, Calendar.MONDAY);
    put(2, Calendar.TUESDAY);
    put(3, Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
    put(4, Calendar.THURSDAY);
    put(5, Calendar.FRIDAY);
    put(6, Calendar.SATURDAY);
    put(7, Calendar.SUNDAY);
}});

private Set<Trigger> createTrigger(Integer dayOfWeek, TimeZone usersTimeZone) {
            Calendar startOfDay = Calendar.getInstance(usersTimeZone);
            Calendar endOfDay = Calendar.getInstance(usersTimeZone);
            startOfDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            startOfDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            startOfDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            startOfDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);

            endOfDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
            endOfDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
            endOfDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
            endOfDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);

            SimpleDateFormat hour = new SimpleDateFormat("H");
            SimpleDateFormat minute = new SimpleDateFormat("m");
            SimpleDateFormat second = new SimpleDateFormat("s");
            SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat("u"); //Monday = 1, Sunday = 7
            hour.setTimeZone(getTimeZone("UTC"));
            minute.setTimeZone(getTimeZone("UTC"));
            second.setTimeZone(getTimeZone("UTC"));
            day.setTimeZone(getTimeZone("UTC"));

            Integer utcStartHour = Integer.valueOf(hour.format(startOfDay.getTime()));
            Integer utcStartMinute = Integer.valueOf(minute.format(startOfDay.getTime()));
            Integer utcStartSecond = Integer.valueOf(second.format(startOfDay.getTime()));
            Integer utcStartDay = Integer.valueOf(day.format(startOfDay.getTime()));

            Integer utcEndHour = Integer.valueOf(hour.format(endOfDay.getTime()));
            Integer utcEndMinute = Integer.valueOf(minute.format(endOfDay.getTime()));
            Integer utcEndSecond = Integer.valueOf(second.format(endOfDay.getTime()));
            Integer utcEndDay = Integer.valueOf(day.format(endOfDay.getTime()));

            Set<Trigger> triggersForJob;
            if (!utcStartDay.equals(utcEndDay)) {
                TimeOfDay trigger1StartTime = new TimeOfDay(utcStartHour, utcStartMinute, utcStartSecond);
                TimeOfDay trigger1EndTime = new TimeOfDay(23, 59, 59);
                Trigger firstTrigger = newTrigger()
                        .withIdentity("trigger 1", "group")
                        .withSchedule(dailyTimeIntervalSchedule()
                                .withIntervalInMinutes(pollingIntervalInMinutes)
                                .onDaysOfTheWeek(SDF_DAY_TO_CALENDAR_DAY.get(utcStartDay)) 
                                .startingDailyAt(trigger1StartTime)
                                .endingDailyAt(trigger1EndTime))
                        .startAt(futureDate(pollingIntervalInMinutes, DateBuilder.IntervalUnit.MINUTE))
                        .build();
                TimeOfDay trigger2StartTime = new TimeOfDay(0, 0, 0);
                TimeOfDay trigger2EndTime = new TimeOfDay(utcEndHour, utcEndMinute, utcEndSecond);
                Trigger secondTrigger = newTrigger()
                        .withIdentity("trigger 2", "group")
                        .withSchedule(dailyTimeIntervalSchedule()
                                .withIntervalInMinutes(pollingIntervalInMinutes)
                                .onDaysOfTheWeek(SDF_DAY_TO_CALENDAR_DAY.get(utcEndDay))
                                .startingDailyAt(trigger2StartTime)
                                .endingDailyAt(trigger2EndTime))
                        .startAt(futureDate(pollingIntervalInMinutes, DateBuilder.IntervalUnit.MINUTE))
                        .build();
                triggersForJob = Sets.newHashSet(firstTrigger, secondTrigger);
            } else {
                TimeOfDay triggerStartTime = new TimeOfDay(utcStartHour, utcStartMinute, utcStartSecond);
                TimeOfDay triggerEndTime = new TimeOfDay(utcEndHour, utcEndMinute, utcEndSecond);
                                Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                        .withIdentity("trigger", "group")
                        .withSchedule(dailyTimeIntervalSchedule()
                                .withIntervalInMinutes(pollingIntervalInMinutes)
                                .onDaysOfTheWeek(SDF_DAY_TO_CALENDAR_DAY.get(utcStartDay))
                                .startingDailyAt(triggerStartTime)
                                .endingDailyAt(triggerEndTime))
                        .startAt(futureDate(pollingIntervalInMinutes, DateBuilder.IntervalUnit.MINUTE))
                        .build();
                triggersForJob = Sets.newHashSet(trigger);
            }
            return triggersForJob;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify appropriate timezone while initializing **TimeOfDay** object for ***startingDailyAt()*** method.
For example:

```
Date startDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 9, 13, 12, 00, 00));
Date endDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 9, 13, 23, 00, 00));

return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withSchedule(dailyTimeIntervalSchedule()
                    .startingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.hourAndMinuteFromDate(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")))
                    .endingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.hourAndMinuteFromDate(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")))
                    .onDaysOfTheWeek(MONDAY_THROUGH_FRIDAY)
                    .withInterval(10, DateBuilder.IntervalUnit.MINUTE))
            .build();
```

But keep in mind you have to express time for **startDate** and **endDate** in UTC.
In that case above trigger will be started each weekday from 8 AM to 7 PM New York time.